# Build libfslcodec-4.0.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 for IMX6Q

Tags: 16.04, make, makefile, autoconf, automake

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.1.15 on IMX6Q "sabresd" Board  and successfully boot. I used [this instruction](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-330147) to install rootfs also I changed distro and solved some issues by myself. Just now I tried compile  libfslcodec-4.0.8 but I have problems. Let me explain the sequences:

1. install all tools I need to compile packages by apt like make, autoconf, gcc, and etc...

autoconf -V -->  autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69

automake --version --> automake (GNU automake) 1.15

make --> GNU Make 4.1

gcc --version --> gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609

2. Download  libfslcodec-4.0.8.bin from [here](http://www.nxp.com/lgfiles/NMG/MAD/YOCTO/libfslcodec-4.0.8.bin). Extract with this command:

```
./libfslcodec-4.0.8.bin --auto-accept –force
```

after that make a Directory with same name.

3. -Run some commands for Auto configure but I can not make and see error "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'." Make file made by auto conf process and had issue, also I have seen a warning during auto conf process :

```
configure.ac:7: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated. For more info, see:
configure.ac:7: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
```

However I checked a link recommended by autoconf warning, it was exactly like the template ([like this](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation)) So I can't make this library. How can I solve this issue? You can see the log below.

```
radio@Radio:~/vps_pack/libfslcodec-4.0.8$ sudo ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --enable-fhw --enable-vpu 
processing .
Running aclocal ...
Running automake --gnu ...
configure.ac:7: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated. For more info, see:
configure.ac:7: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --prefix=/usr --enable-fhw --enable-vpu ...
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes

Enable FHW option

Enable VPU option
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libfslaudiocodec.pc
config.status: creating libfslvideocodec.pc
Configure result (with uni_audio: yes):
Enabled audio codec:
peq
src
aacdec
mp3dec
mp3enc
vorbisdec
bsacdec
flacdec
sbcenc
g726
g711
g723
g729
amrnb
amrwb
Disabled audio codec:
Enabled video codec:
deinterlace
h264dec
mpeg2dec
mpeg4aspdec
jpegdec
jpegenc
bmpdec
pngdec
gifdec
Disabled video codec:
Now type `make' to compile.
radio@Radio:~/vps_pack/libfslcodec-4.0.8$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
radio@Radio:~/vps_pack/libfslcodec-4.0.8$
```

Comment: The `.bin` file in your link appears to contain pre-built binary files and libraries as well as source code - presumably `make` decides that they don't need to be rebuilt before installing.

Comment: Modified part 2 Please see that.It is not bin file and need Extract.

Comment: If you look in `libfslcodec-4.0.8/release/exe/` or `libfslcodec-4.0.8/release/lib/` what do you see? I'm betting it is pre-built executables and libraries

Comment: It is not  pre-build lib some parts need to compile again. Please see [Here](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-330147?sr=search&searchId=9a531c23-2caf-4add-a8b1-10e98d75cc53&searchIndex=1) and looking  "5: Setting Ubuntu on target -> Get and Install the BSP packages (EULA required)." Please see Line 25. You can see a part need to make and make install.(Lines 28 and 29).